# remove a member of array in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

In Postgresql, if I have an array of team_id in my table for example `team_id=[2,3,5,7]`
when I want to remove 7 from the array of team_id what is the command?

I write :

```
SELECT array_remove(ARRAY[team_id],7)
```

but it is not correct

Answer (score 1):

The array keyword is unnecessary:

```
select array_remove(team_id, 7)
```